# React JS Header Switching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-router

I have a Website in React which has common header and footer everything is functional and Routing is perfect.I need to have a standalone page which it's own header and footer and routing URL as well. I have created the standalone page but when I redirecting to App.js common header and common footer also comes which I don't want.Please help me out it's React 18 by the way. And prior thanks for the helpful comments

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";
import AllOffers from "./pages/AllOffers/AllOffers";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import OfferDetails from "./components/OfferDetails/OfferDetails";
import FoundationDayOffer from "./pages/FoundationDayOffer/FoundationDayOffer";
import RamadanOffer from "./pages/RamadanOffer/RamadanOffer";

function App() {
  return (
    // STAND ALONE PAGE ROUTES STARTS
    // (
    //   <BrowserRouter>
    //     <div>
    //       <Routes>
    //         <Route
    //           path="foundation-day-offer"
    //           element={<FoundationDayOffer />}
    //         />
    //         <Route path="ramadan-offer" element={<RamadanOffer />} />
    //       </Routes>
    //     </div>
    //   </BrowserRouter>
    // ),
     // STAND ALONE PAGE ROUTES ENDS
    (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <main>
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="all-offers" element={<AllOffers />} />
            <Route path="offer-details/:id" element={<OfferDetails />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  );
}

export default App;
```